# Error during custom odata client creation

Tags: typescript, sap-cloud-sdk

**EDITTED AFTER Deeksha's answer**

Following the [blog post](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/cloudsdk-js-generator.html) to create a custom OData client using Cloud SDK's Generator for JavaScript & [Deeksha's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70244748/2122912), I run the following command to create my OData client:

`sdk_test % generate-odata-client --inputDir resources/ --outputDir out/ --forceOverwrite`

I have used the edmx of the candidate api as suggested in the post (e.g., edmx file downloaded from [here](https://api.sap.com/api/RCMCandidate/overview)). Version of the generator:

```
sdk_test % generate-odata-client --version                                              
[2021-12-07T09:08:00.714Z] INFO     (generator-cli): Parsing args...
1.52.0
```

And I am using mac.

I have had the exact same problem for my own project.
There are many suggestion for similar typescript errors on the internet, including addition of `"dom"` to the libraries in `tsconfig.json`. I already have this option, and anyways I don't think my config is relevant for the generator.

I am getting the following error:

```
[2021-12-07T09:00:19.229Z] ERROR    (generator-cli): ErrorWithCause: Generation of services failed.
    at new ErrorWithCause (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@sap-cloud-sdk/generator/node_modules/@sap-cloud-sdk/util/dist/error-with-cause.js:34:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@sap-cloud-sdk/generator/dist/generator-cli.js:33:18
Caused by:
Error: Compilation Errors:
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/node_modules/@types/superagent/index.d.ts:10:30 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Blob'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/node_modules/@types/superagent/index.d.ts:13:3231 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XMLHttpRequest'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/Candidate.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/Candidate.ts:4:135 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/Candidate.ts:16:13174 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/Candidate.ts:16:13226 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/Candidate.ts:16:13410 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/Candidate.ts:16:15365 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/Candidate.ts:16:15568 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/Candidate.ts:16:15659 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/Candidate.ts:16:15704 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Certificates.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Certificates.ts:4:129 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Certificates.ts:8:4906 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Certificates.ts:8:6277 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Certificates.ts:8:6558 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Certificates.ts:8:6695 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Certificates.ts:8:6763 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Education.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Education.ts:4:129 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Education.ts:8:6019 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Education.ts:8:7583 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Education.ts:8:7855 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Education.ts:8:7986 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Education.ts:8:8051 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_InsideWorkExperience.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_InsideWorkExperience.ts:4:129 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_InsideWorkExperience.ts:8:3187 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_InsideWorkExperience.ts:8:4375 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_InsideWorkExperience.ts:8:4680 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_InsideWorkExperience.ts:8:4833 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_InsideWorkExperience.ts:8:4909 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Languages.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Languages.ts:4:129 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Languages.ts:8:3140 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Languages.ts:8:4081 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Languages.ts:8:4353 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Languages.ts:8:4484 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_Languages.ts:8:4549 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_OutsideWorkExperience.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_OutsideWorkExperience.ts:4:129 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_OutsideWorkExperience.ts:8:6206 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_OutsideWorkExperience.ts:8:8038 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_OutsideWorkExperience.ts:8:8346 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_OutsideWorkExperience.ts:8:8501 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_OutsideWorkExperience.ts:8:8578 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_TalentPool.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_TalentPool.ts:4:129 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_TalentPool.ts:8:3372 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_TalentPool.ts:8:4255 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_TalentPool.ts:8:4530 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_TalentPool.ts:8:4663 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_TalentPool.ts:8:4729 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_TalentPoolcorp.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_TalentPoolcorp.ts:4:129 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_TalentPoolcorp.ts:8:3421 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_TalentPoolcorp.ts:8:4365 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_TalentPoolcorp.ts:8:4652 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_TalentPoolcorp.ts:8:4793 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateBackground_TalentPoolcorp.ts:8:4863 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateComments.ts:3:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateComments.ts:3:129 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateComments.ts:7:3434 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateComments.ts:7:4162 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateComments.ts:7:4387 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateComments.ts:7:4494 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateComments.ts:7:4547 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateLight.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateLight.ts:4:135 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateLight.ts:16:13284 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateLight.ts:16:13341 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateLight.ts:16:13540 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateLight.ts:16:15765 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateLight.ts:16:15983 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateLight.ts:16:16084 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateLight.ts:16:16134 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateProfileExtension.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateProfileExtension.ts:4:115 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateProfileExtension.ts:7:2203 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateProfileExtension.ts:7:2914 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateProfileExtension.ts:7:3165 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateProfileExtension.ts:7:3288 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateProfileExtension.ts:7:3349 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateTags.ts:3:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateTags.ts:3:121 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateTags.ts:7:1735 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateTags.ts:7:2256 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateTags.ts:7:2465 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateTags.ts:7:2564 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/CandidateTags.ts:7:2613 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Certificates.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Certificates.ts:4:115 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Certificates.ts:7:4550 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Certificates.ts:7:5875 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Certificates.ts:7:6165 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Certificates.ts:7:6308 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Certificates.ts:7:6379 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Education.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Education.ts:4:115 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Education.ts:7:5669 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Education.ts:7:7208 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Education.ts:7:7489 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Education.ts:7:7626 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Education.ts:7:7694 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_InsideWorkExperience.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_InsideWorkExperience.ts:4:115 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_InsideWorkExperience.ts:7:2815 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_InsideWorkExperience.ts:7:3923 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_InsideWorkExperience.ts:7:4237 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_InsideWorkExperience.ts:7:4396 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_InsideWorkExperience.ts:7:4475 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Languages.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Languages.ts:4:115 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Languages.ts:7:2790 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Languages.ts:7:3670 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Languages.ts:7:3951 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Languages.ts:7:4088 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_Languages.ts:7:4156 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_OutsideWorkExperience.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_OutsideWorkExperience.ts:4:115 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_OutsideWorkExperience.ts:7:5832 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_OutsideWorkExperience.ts:7:7612 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_OutsideWorkExperience.ts:7:7929 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_OutsideWorkExperience.ts:7:8090 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_OutsideWorkExperience.ts:7:8170 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_TalentPool.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_TalentPool.ts:4:115 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_TalentPool.ts:7:3026 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_TalentPool.ts:7:3843 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_TalentPool.ts:7:4127 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_TalentPool.ts:7:4266 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_TalentPool.ts:7:4335 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_TalentPoolcorp.ts:4:101 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'FieldBuilder'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_TalentPoolcorp.ts:4:115 - error TS2305: Module '"@sap-cloud-sdk/core"' has no exported member 'OrderableEdmTypeField'.
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_TalentPoolcorp.ts:7:3067 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EdmTypeField<EntityT, FieldT>' requires 2 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_TalentPoolcorp.ts:7:3937 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_TalentPoolcorp.ts:7:4233 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_TalentPoolcorp.ts:7:4380 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
/Users/d070808/Downloads/sdk_test/out/rcm-candidate-service/JobApplicationSnapshot_TalentPoolcorp.ts:7:4453 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Field<EntityT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@sap-cloud-sdk/generator/node_modules/@sap-cloud-sdk/generator-common/dist/compiler.js:80:31)
    at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@sap-cloud-sdk/generator/node_modules/@sap-cloud-sdk/generator-common/dist/compiler.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@sap-cloud-sdk/generator/node_modules/@sap-cloud-sdk/generator-common/dist/compiler.js:14:53)
    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@sap-cloud-sdk/generator/node_modules/@sap-cloud-sdk/generator-common/dist/compiler.js:5:58)
```

Comment: Could you add the content of your `package.json` and the output of `npm ls`? There may be a version conflict which could lead to these errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CLI you are using is going to be deprecated soon and is therefore not maintained. That's a potential failure reason.

Please use the new SAP Cloud SDK's Odata generator to generate your custom clients. You can install the client by running:

```
npm install -g @sap-cloud-sdk/generator
```

and executing the below command to generate the client:

```
generate-odata-client --inputDir path/to/your/service-specifications --outputDir path/to/store/generated/modules
```

Detailed documentation can be found [here](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/js/features/odata/generate-odata-client).

Comment: Shall I remove the `@sap-cloud-sdk/cli` from my installations?

Comment: Yes, you can remove this dependency.

Comment: In addition to the Deeksha's suggestion, I needed to delete the `chai` lib (together with its types) from my dependencies. After that it creted the client.